# Android xmpp client xabber

Tags: android, xmpp, chat

I have been searching for Android xmpp clients. I came to know about asmack for android. I have also found xabber for android [here](https://github.com/redsolution/xabber-android) . I have downloaded the code and able to run it successfully. I am not able to get any documentation of xabber APIs.

1. Is it possible to use this xabber client for my custom XMPP server.
2. If u know any other good Xmpp clients for android , please suggest
   me.

Comment: For desktop, you can install Spark - https://igniterealtime.org/projects/spark/.

Answer (score 3):

[Smack](https://github.com/igniterealtime/Smack) is Java XMPP library, [asmack](https://github.com/flowdalic/asmack) is a Smack build environment for android, it is well maintained and you can get precompiled libraries. You can view Smack documentation and samples [here](http://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/smack/docs/latest/documentation/). Xabber - is one of XMPP clients which uses Smack library(custom fork with some modifications) and you may use official Smack documentation when digging into xabber sources.

Comment: new FileTransferManager(connection);
what connection is required in this parameter,,, xmppConnection default or with certain properties ???

Answer (score 2):

You should definitely have a look at Yaxim:
https://github.com/pfleidi/yaxim

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to use this xabber client for my custom XMPP server.

Yes, but i'm not sure.

> If u know any other good Xmpp clients for android , please suggest me.

The best list of applications that implements XMPP is on xmpp foundation own site. https://xmpp.org/xmpp-software/clients/

I hope help you.